# Update-Database command not working successfully

Tags: c#, entity-framework

### Problem

I am using EF 6.1.3 I add migrations when I use update-database command my last added migration not execute.

### Image

[image]

### Image2

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the error that you're getting? Is there anything in the output window or console?

Comment: there is no error but my migration not execute when update database calls

Comment: Take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx
Check out the **Get Script** part - save your migration to the script and run it on a DB yourself - then check what the error is and post it here

Comment: @ironstone13 script is empty

Comment: But the migration file in cs is not empty, right? There is something in GenericAtt...cs, right?

Comment: yes it is not empty

Comment: Are you 100% certain that connection strings are the same - i.e. migrations are set to apply to the same DB that you're looking at?
I'm afraid I can't help much without seeing the error or the code.

Comment: Try `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase`. If that comes back blank you are not pointing at the right place.